# Mouse dissapears in lower screen, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, radeon, amd-graphics

My mouse dissapears if i move it in the lower half of my screen. The mouse is still functioning in the lower half. (I can see buttons react when i move over them or click them). The problem starts directly after booting.

I reinstalled the whole system (formatting and reinstalling ubuntu). This did help but the problem reapeared after two days.

If i lower the screen resolution the problem dissapears.

I am using this Graphic Card: 
HD 5750 700M 512 MB DDR5 DP HDMI Dual DVI
PCI-E

My computer is a PC with 16.04 LTS and an external screen. 
Resolution: 1920*1080

The graphic devices seems not to be properly recognized by the system. 
[Screenshot "Additional Drivers" Graphic Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Oz2.jpg) There is no effect if i change it to "Do not use the device".

I tried installing ADMGPU-PRO Driver vor Linux (http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx). This caused problems at the login (after clicking entering the password and pressing enter the screen went black and then the login page reappeared) and reduced the screen resulution to very low. I was not possible to select a higher screen resolution.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the refresh rate to 24Hz solved the problem for me.
25Hz and 30Hz did not work. I hive no clue why.

Sharp TV Flat-screen (1920:1080) as display,
Xubuntu 16.04
Integrated AMD/ATI RS780 [Radeon HD 3200]